# Ajax call return function instead of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpresponse, jquery-deferred

I make a request with jquery $ajax call, but it returns the callback function itself, instead of the correct data response and showing the message "ReferenceError: recapCB is not defined";

```
var recapMonthDEF = $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: getAnalyticsApiURL('recapMonth'),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json",
    });

    $.when(lastMonthSessionsDEF, recapMonthDEF).always(function(){
        $('#Dashboard-tabs-1 .toggle input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    recapMonthDEF.always(recapCB);



    var recapCB = function(response){

        if($('#newUsers').length == 0) return;

        data = response;

        var percent = parseFloat(parseFloat(data.percentNewSessions).toFixed(1));
        var percentDiff = parseFloat((100 - percent).toFixed(1));

        var sessionDuration = moment().startOf('day').seconds(data.sessionDuration).format('H:mm:ss');

        $('#analitycs-session').html(data.sessions);
        $('#analitycs-users').html(data.users);
        $('#analitycs-pageviews').html(data.pageviews);
        $('#analitycs-sessionsPerUser').html(parseFloat(data.sessionsPerUser).toFixed(2));
        $('#analitycs-sessionDuration').html(sessionDuration);
        $('#analitycs-newUsers').html(data.newUsers);

    };
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: so use the response object to reference the text/json/

Comment: the response object doesn't have a field containing data

Comment: What is `contentType: "application/json",` doing there? You're making a GET request so there is no request body to describe the type of and you're using JSONP so you can't override the request headers!

Answer (score 1):

> but it returns the callback function itself

Your screenshot is not showing the callback function. It is showing a jqXHR object.

See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> **jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });** (added in jQuery 1.6)
>  An alternative construct to the
>   complete callback option, the .always() method replaces the deprecated
>   .complete() method.
>
> In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the
>   same as those of .done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For
>   failed requests the arguments are the same as those of .fail(): the
>   jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to deferred.always()
>   for implementation details.

Since you are getting a jqXHR object, you must be triggering the error state.

Most likely this is because the URL you are using is not giving a JSONP response.

---

> ReferenceError: recapCB is not defined

You define `recapCB` on the line **after** you try to use it.